# How to clone a MarkLogic database

Tags: marklogic

I tried the following xquery example but it seems to be only returning a configuration script and not actually creating the NewDB on the server. What are the steps to actually create the DB and forest?

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

  import module namespace admin = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/admin" 
          at "/MarkLogic/admin.xqy";

  let $config := admin:get-configuration()
  return
  admin:database-copy($config, xdmp:database("ExistingDB"), "NewDB")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing step is to call [admin:save-configuration()](http://docs.marklogic.com/admin:save-configuration). Most of the admin function help you set up a revised configuration, with the idea that you'll apply all changes at once by calling the above function.

Additional reference: [General Steps for Scripting Administrative Tasks](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin-api/usingAPI#id_41402) -- part of the [Scripting Administrative Tasks Guide](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin-api)

Comment: One probably also need to copy forests, and attach those to the database. Also don't forget that this database-copy function only copies database settings, and no contents.

Comment: Thanks. I am going to give it a try later today.